# Automate Microsoft SDK for Java 4.0 installer

Tags: automation, installation, autoit

I am trying to install Microsoft SDK for Java 4.0 for one of my legacy projects using AutoIt.

[image]

On the first setup window there is a small where I need to activate that screen and select enter. But it is not happening. Below is the code I am using:

```
Run("SDKJava40.exe")
Sleep(500)

WinWait("Microsoft SDK for Java 4.0 Setup", "Welcome to the")
WinActivate("Microsoft SDK for Java 4.0", "Welcome to the")
Sleep(1000)
Send("{ENTER}")

WinWait("Software License Agreement", "Please read the following")
WinActivate("Software License Agreement", "Please read the following")
Sleep(1000)
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things you can try:

1. Check **AutoIt v3 Window Info** for the exact window title and text.
2. Add administrator rights `#RequireAdmin` on the top.
3. Try to use `ControlClick`